# Devise: Adding first_name to Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**Rails 3.1**
**Devise 1.4.2**
I've added first_name and last_name columns to devise's User table.
Then I've used to console to add a first_name and last_name for my first user.

Now, my `application.html.erb` displays my first name and last name thanks to the following code after I've made sure the user is logged in:

```
<%= current_user.first_name %> <%= current_user.last_name %>(<%= current_user.email %>)
```

Here's my problem: when I try to register a new user via the new user form I've created, the first_name and last_name are not stored in the database or something... because when I log in with the new user the code I have on my `application.html.erb` does not display the first and last name.

Here's the text fields for the first and last name in the `new.html.erb`:

```
<p><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :first_name %></p>

<p><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :last_name %></p>

<p><%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.email_field :email %></p>
```

I'd also like to know how to add validation for these new columns I've created (first_name and last_name).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Rails 3

By default, devise makes all attributes protected. For any attribute you want to be able to mass assign (e.g via a form), you need to explicitly allow it in your model:

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
```

It worked in your console because you probably did something like this:

```
@user = User.first
@user.first_name = "foo"
@user.save
```

But this won't work if the attribute is not accessible:

```
@user = User.new(:first_name => "foo")
@user.save
```

You'll should see a warning "Can't mass assign protected attributes" in your log file.

For validations, check out the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html) or [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html). For example, to ensure a full name is provided, add

```
validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
```

to your model.

Comment: I thought I had to use a different syntax for the field names of the devise columns :( thanks man

Answer (score 1):

#### Rails 4+

I have solved the problem. It will also work for rails 4+.

**Step 1:** Run New Migration

$ rails generate migration AddFieldToUsers first_name:string last_name:string

Optionally, you may wish to change the columns to `null: false` and within the user model `validates presence: true`.

```
 class AddFieldToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string, null: false
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string, null: false
  end
 end
```

`$ rake db:migrate`

**Step 2:**
Add these code on the devise views. If you haven't generated them already, you will need: `rails generate devise:views users`

```
  # app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
  # app/views/devise/registraitons/new.html.erb

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
```

**Step 3:**  add this to your application controller

```
  # app/controllers/application_controller.rb

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = %i[first_name last_name email password password_confirmation remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you forgot to set `attr_accessible` for your new attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to your application controller

```
protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }


    end
```